# Secure account creating in your own iPhone app

Tags: iphone, security, httprequest, account

We are currently trying to create our own system, where users can create user accounts using their iPhone. However, we're not sure how we can securely create accounts for users with their own password set and everything. I've been told this is only possible with HTTP requests, which doesn't really look safe.

Comment: Parse (https://parse.com) is great for this. You won't have to create your own system.

Answer (score 0):

You can always encrypt the data you send via http

See answer to this question for the link to the tutorial:
[AES 128 Encryption for iPhone HTTP Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312145/aes-128-encryption-for-iphone-http-stream)